# Java Error: 'else' without 'if'

Tags: java, syntax

I am trying to compile and execute a program however it gives me the error:

Dice.java:20: error: 'else' without 'if'
   else if (roll1 == roll2) {
   ^
Dice.java:44: error: 'else' without 'if'
   else if (roll1 == roll2) {
   ^
2 errors

Please help check my code and let me know what I can do to fix the problem. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

 public static void main(string[] args); {
   int turn;
 turn = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);

  while (score1 <= 75 || score2 <= 75);

  if (turn = 1 & (roll1 != roll2)) {
   roll1 = roll1.random();
   roll2 = roll2.random();
   score1 += (roll1 + roll2);
   System.out.prinln("Player 1 rolls a" + roll1 + "and a" + roll2);
   turn = 2;
   else if (roll1 == roll2) {
    while (roll1 == roll2) {
     System.out.println("Player 1 gets to roll again");
     roll1 = roll1.random();
     roll2 = roll2.random();
     score1 += (roll1 + roll2);
     System.out.prinln("Player 1 rolls a" + roll1 + "and a" + roll2);
     score1 += (roll1 + roll2);
    }
   } 
   else {
    if (score1 >= 75) {
     System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
     turn = 2;
    }
   }
  }

  if (turn = 2 & roll1 != roll2) {
   roll1 = roll1.random();
   roll2 = roll2.random();
   score2 += (roll1 + roll2);
   System.out.prinln("Player 2 rolls a" + roll1 + "and a" + roll2);
   turn = 1;
   else if (roll1 == roll2) {
    while (roll1 == roll2);
    System.out.println("Player 2 gets to roll again");
    score2 += (roll1 + roll2);
    roll1 = roll1.random();
    roll2 = roll2.random();
    System.out.println("Player 2 gets to roll again");
   } 
   else {
    if (score2 >= 75) {
     System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
     turn = 1;
    }
   }
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: get rid of this semicolon `while (score1 <= 75 || score2 <= 75);`

Comment: doing assigment `if (turn = 1` not comparision

Comment: need `}` before `else if (roll1 == roll2) {`

Comment: I got rid of the semicolon I don't understand the doing assignment if (turn = 1 not comparison part

Comment: You want `if (turn == 1)`  `turn = 1` assigns the value of `1` to the variable `turn`

Comment: try use an IDE like Eclipse, it will maybe give you more hints as to what is wrong with your code

Comment: Better to write using IDE as mentioned by @ScaryWombat and there are other errors like `string` must be `String` in main method, and `score1` , `score2` not defined bla bla......nesting if else condition not in proper way, you can not use `else if` without its `if`.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes but I can't shake the else without if error

Comment: is there a way for you to send me the correct code so I can see what I'm not doing right?

Comment: `else without if`, take a look at what is enclosed in your `if` statements and then think about what `if - else if - else` statements should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is a lot of syntax error and then `if else` conditional statement error. I java you need to define a variable, without defining you can not use them.

Secondly you need to learn how to use Class and its methods.
**While debugging your code, see what I have got and I have put comment on the codes that your need to write.**

```
import java.util.Random; //Not used in your code, no need to import

public class Dice {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int turn;
    turn = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
    int score1 = 0;
    int score2 = 0;
    int roll1 = 0;
    int roll2 = 0;

  while (score1 <= 75 || score2 <= 75){

    if (turn == 1 & (roll1 != roll2)) {
        //roll1 = roll1.random(); //please correct this
        //roll2 = roll2.random(); //put correct code that you want
        score1 += (roll1 + roll2);
        System.out.println("Player 1 rolls a" + roll1 + "and a" + roll2);
        turn = 2;
    }

    else if (roll1 == roll2) {
        while (roll1 == roll2) {
         System.out.println("Player 1 gets to roll again");
         //roll1 = roll1.random();
         //roll2 = roll2.random();
         score1 += (roll1 + roll2);
         System.out.println("Player 1 rolls a" + roll1 + "and a" + roll2);
         score1 += (roll1 + roll2);
        }
     } 

      else {
        if (score1 >= 75) {
         System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
         turn = 2;
        }
     }


    if (turn == 2 & roll1 != roll2) {
        //roll1 = roll1.random();
        //roll2 = roll2.random();
        score2 += (roll1 + roll2);
        System.out.println("Player 2 rolls a" + roll1 + "and a" + roll2);
        turn = 1;
    }

    else if (roll1 == roll2) {
          while (roll1 == roll2);
          System.out.println("Player 2 gets to roll again");
          score2 += (roll1 + roll2);
          //roll1 = roll1.random();
          //roll2 = roll2.random();
          System.out.println("Player 2 gets to roll again");
     } 
    else {
          if (score2 >= 75) {
           System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
           turn = 1;
          }
     }

  }

 }

}
```

To get rid of syntax error, you can use IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse and to understand how conditional statement work, please see

```
if(condition1){  
//code to be executed if condition1 is true  
}else if(condition2){  
//code to be executed if condition2 is true  
}  
else if(condition3){  
//code to be executed if condition3 is true  
}  
...  
else{  
//code to be executed if all the conditions are false  
}
```

Please Look at JAVA step by step.
This is the link where you can start [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm) 
Search some video tutorials about writing JAVA programs.

Comment: remember there is commented line of code that you need to change, and put valid java code.

Comment: I have changed the code but I'm not too sure yet if it will work. Will download the IDE to check.